# unable to extract data from div section

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to extract the Host name and Ip  from following url, but it returns nothing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3abuildersinmysore.com&run=toolpage"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'tool-result-body'})
#table = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed tool-result-table'})
print(divs)
```

Comment: what is the result of running this code?  what did you expect to get?

Comment: For a domain there might be more ips as a result - you didn't specify the one you are referring to...

Comment: @game0ver So  how can i get it

Comment: @BreaksSoftware This code return blank [ ], i expect whatever we get from extarcting div class

Comment: First of all the url from which you are trying to extract the Hostname and IP address do not show any Hostname and IP. Secondly, I tried with google.com as the URL and it show the Hostname/IP but when using the code, it doesn't come as the content.

Comment: @devd i try with selenium webdriver, but also found nothinh in content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep 

obj = webdriver.Chrome(#path to chrome driver)
obj.get('https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3abuildersinmysore.com&run=toolpage')
sleep(5)     
#IP Address
print(obj.find_element_by_class_name('table-column-IP_Address').text)
#Hostname
print(obj.find_element_by_class_name('table-column-Hostname').text)
```

Comment: It's give the following error, is it working on your pc? selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"table-column-IP_Address"}

Comment: @Pratap now try, i added sleep after get